# Replace `'react'` with `"react"` eslint(prettier/prettier)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, tslint

Local environment:

- IDE: vscode
- Language mode: `JavasSript React`

```js
import React from 'react';
```

A syntax error message appears:

```
Replace `'react'` with `"react"`eslint(prettier/prettier)
```

How can I configure it?

---

in `.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  rules: {
    quotes: [1, 'single'],
  }
};
```

Thank you for your answer.  `Rules` can be solved

But I want to know where `@react-native-community` comes from. I didn't see this file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like this, it works for me.

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2"
  },
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "react-app",
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

.prettierrc

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 80,
  "tabWidth": 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quotes). It specifies the singleQuote option, which could be configured in a configuration file for prettier or in the package.json, i.e.:

```
"prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

For other options of configuration, have a look [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

In eslint/ prettier configuration, you have enabled `double quotes`.

check the following:

- goto vscode settings `(ctrl + ,) (cmd + ,)` and search for `single quote` and disable it.